redirect nested parents routes to child route
I have routes set up with three nested levels. Whenever someone goes to the top level path which is /home I would like to redirect it to the child parent, which has a path profile. So the final path should be /home/profile, but when I go to just /home I get warning

Matched leaf route at location "/home" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

//routes

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='home'>
      <Route index={true} path='profile'>
        <Route index={true} element={<Profile />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>


//Update also tried the <Navigate /> already but that does not work.

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='home' element={<Navigate to='profile' />}> // Also tried to='home/profile'
      <Route index={true} path='profile'>
        <Route index={true} element={<Profile />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

Based on my nested routes, how can I make it so that going to just /home will be able to show Profile component?
Edit:
I would like to have the redirect from the parent route /home to the nested parent route /profile without using the element prop since from my understanding, having an element prop in the parent Route will cause problem in rendering the child route element when using index.
So basically I want to use index prop in route /Profile so that when someone goes to /home, it will default to the nested index route /profile which in turn will then also show the final nested route with element={<Profile} /> but as mentioned it does not seem to work

Index routes can't have children. Use the first code example from the duplicate to use an index route to render a match to the "/home" parent route path, and nest the "profile" sub-route up a level as a sibling to the index route.

you can achieve the redirect from the parent route to the child route by using the Navigate component within your route configuration
import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Profile from './Profile'; 
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='home' element={<Navigate to='/home/profile' />} />
            <Route path='home/profile' element={<Profile />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;


The issue is, I need kind of two parent routes. You can see in my example, the Routes for paths home and Profile are parent routes and it wraps the final route which has index set to true with a element as well. But if the user puts just /home in the url without /home/profile no component shows and I get the warning message above. Thats why I need it to redirect, but I tried adding the Naviagate to home route and profile route but i does not do anything and I still get warning.

Can you please check my updated question which has more details on what I am trying to accomplish? Please try setting up the routes like I have with 3 nested layers not just one level like in your answer. You will see it will not work when it is more than one level for default index routes
